# Двоякое толкование предложения

Tags: синтаксис, тире

Сегодня столкнулась с проблемой, касающейся определения грамматической основы в предложении, которое, по моему мнению, может трактоваться по-разному.

*Мерить ветер не хватит вёдер.*

Если мы не ставим тире, получается обычное простое предложение, в котором присутствует только один главный член (не хватит), обстоятельство (мерить) и два дополнения (ветер, вёдер).

*Мерить ветер – не хватит вёдер.*

При этом в случае постановки тире мы получаем БСП. Если (мерить ветер), [не хватит вёдер].

Можете, пожалуйста, развеять сомнения по поводу двоякого смысла. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эта пословица и правда существует в разных видах - с тире и без него:

http://delovremja.ru/publ/22-1-0-854   *Мерять ветер - не хватит ведер. Морские пословицы.*

*Мерять ветер не станет ведер.*  http://www.epwr.ru/proverb/txt_168.php

И даже в таком виде: Ветер — ведрами не измерить…

Есть ещё *Солнышка в мешок не поймаешь, а ведрами ветра не смеряешь.* Так говорят о бесполезной, бестолковой работе. Смысл, скорее всего, в последнем варианте общий для всех, пунктуация меняет грамматику, но не смысл: бесполезно мерить ветер вёдрами.

Согласна с Вами, конструкции действительно разные. В школьных учебниках конструкцию с тире приводят как пример БСП с условными отношениями: http://www.mygdz.com/otvet/russkij-yazyk-9-klass-tro-19b98.html    ГДЗ.Русский язык.9 класс.Л.А.Тростенцова...

Если тире убрать, получается простое предложение.

Answer (score 0):

Если извлекать смысл из *самого* предложения, то он **не** изменяется пунктуацией: можно предположить только, что измерять скорость ветра предполагается при помощи вёдер (напр. поставив перевёрнутые вёдра разного размера одно на другое и подсчитав, при каком их количестве конструкция рассыпается от ветра). При этом пунктуация может изменить только интонацию и соответствующую эмоциональную окраску высказывания, при всей фантастичности метода измерения.

Изменить смысл в варианте с тире мог бы *внешний* контекст, поясняющий, что вёдра не имеют отношения к методу измерения. Например, не хватит их в результате похищения злоумышленником при отлучке метеоролога на измерение скорости ветра.

Comment: Вёдра разного размера? Разного — для усугубления фантастичности метода?

Comment: Нет, чтобы меньшие, верхние, умещались на доньях нижних. При одинаковых ведрах они бы надевались одно на другое.

Comment: И тогда, что напрашивается, устоявшую пирамидку люди назвали Вёдра?